# Customizing parsley.js to show an icon near the offending field

Tags: javascript, css, parsley.js

I would like parsley.js to show an icon near the label of every offending field. Something like:

```
<label class="warning" for="name">Name</label>
```

(http://jsfiddle.net/7q3ktchb/)

Essentially, I would like to configure parsley to set a class of the label of the offending field.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using the events `parsley:field:success` and `parsley:field:error`

```
<form id="myForm">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" data-parsley-minlength="5" data-parsley-required="true" />

    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input class="cuiMessageWarningImg" type="text" name="email" data-parsley-required="true"
        data-parsley-type="email" />

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    $('#myForm').parsley();

    $.listen('parsley:field:error', function(ParsleyField) {
        ParsleyField.$element.prev('label').addClass('warning');
    });

    $.listen('parsley:field:success', function(ParsleyField) {
        ParsleyField.$element.prev('label').removeClass('warning');
    });
</script>
```

Check this [**working example in jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/milz/787pvxhu/)